# How to add prefix to metric in vertx - prometheus

Tags: java, prometheus, vert.x

vertx_http_server_request_bytes_bucket{method="GET",le="7.330077518506E12",} 1.0
vertx_http_server_request_bytes_bucket{method="GET",le="8.796093022207E12",} 1.0
vertx_http_server_request_bytes_bucket{method="GET",le="1.0262108525908E13",} 1.0

How to add prefix to metric name in vertx prometheus?
example : appName_vertx_http_server_request_bytes_bucket{method="GET",le="1.0262108525908E13",} 1.0

Answer (score 0):

The configuration cannot implement changing the metric name. However, the **record rules** setting can create a new metric, although record rules are not used in this way at the beginning, but it can achieve this effect.

You can try it if you need to modify the number of indicators is relatively small.You can try to create rule_file by following text. And reload prometheus to make it take effect.

```
groups:
  - name: vertx_http_server_request_bytes_bucket_merics
    rules:
  - record: appName_vertx_http_server_request_bytes_bucket
    expr: vertx_http_server_request_bytes_bucket
```

recording rules document for your reference.
[Recording Rules Doc.](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/recording_rules/)

Comment: in microservice, Can it distinguish metrics from multiple apps?

Comment: Hi, @LoiNguyenTri . seems not ,  but may i know what your purpose to rename metric?

Comment: maybe i want to distinguish metric between apps in metrics browsers of grafana.
just make it more clear.

Comment: Hi @LoiNguyenTri , i think It is more friendly to use different label values to distinguish.

Comment: okay, it's also true
thanks .

Answer (score 0):

You can have json config file with names for each of the metrics,

please do check MicrometerMetricsOptionsConverter -> case "metricsNaming":

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).